# Can more than one wall be used by the same Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook-pages, spam-prevention

I want users to pick which content they want to follow that is related to my page. Even though I want to post everything, I'd rather not spam them. Is it possible to let them choose the topics they want to subscribe?

Something like this:

- Main wall: posts once or twice a day
- All: around 20 posts a day
- Galaxy: around 2 posts a day

Comment: Have you tried making 3 different facebook pages?

Comment: @slybloty How would that solve the problem?

Comment: Each page would show the content that you want certain users to see.

Comment: @slybloty I'm not looking for an alternative. The problem is whether it's possible or not to have more than one wall.

Comment: As far as I know and have seen there's only one wall. I was trying to offer you alternatives.

Comment: @slybloty Thank you. I think I'll ask on UserUX how convenient your alternative would be for users because I really have no idea if it would work.